# Solving second order ODE - Hermite polynomial and Kummer confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function, hermite-polynomials, kummer-theory

I have the following system of two second order ODEs:

\begin{align}
(L -D)V+Q^{-1}g(x)=0
\end{align}

where

\begin{align}
L = \frac{1}{2} \sigma_{x}^{2} I \partial_{x}^{2}+(A - a_1 x) I \partial_{x} 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
D=diag(a_{1,-},a_{1,+})\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
Q=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a_{1,-}& a_{1,+}    \\
 1 &   1   
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
J = (J_{x}(x),J_{\pi}(x))^\top
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
V=Q^{-1}J
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
g(x) = 2( \lambda_{x} x,\lambda_{\pi} (a_{0} + a_{1}x))^{\top}
\end{align}

To solve it, I need to find the complementary function and the particular integral.

I know that the result for the complementary function is as follows:
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{V}_{1}=f_{1,-}F_{1,-}(x)+f_{2,-}F_{2,-}(x),\\
\boldsymbol{V}_{2}=f_{1,+}F_{1,+}(x)+f_{2,+}F_{2,+}(x),
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
F_{1,\pm}(x)&=H_{-\frac{a_{1,\pm}}{a_{1}}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a_{1}} x}{\sigma_{x} }-\frac{A}{\sqrt{a_{1}} \sigma_{x}}\right)\\
F_{2,\pm}(x)&=\, _1F_1\left(\frac{a_{1,\pm}}{2 a_{1}};\frac{1}{2};\left(\frac{\sqrt{a_{1}} x}{\sigma_{x}
   }-\frac{A}{\sqrt{a_{1}} \sigma_{x} }\right)^2\right)
\end{align}
where $H_{n}(z)$ is the $n$'th degree Hermite polynomial and $_1F_1(a,b,z)$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.

But I am very confused about how to do this first step. I try to solve the homogeneous equation:

\begin{align}
(L -D)V=0
\end{align}

But I struggle to relate the result to the Hermite polynomial and the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function. Is this first step the right one?